# Confirmation Message not working Using Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am fetching data from database using ajax in codeigniter and now i am trying to put "delete confirmation box"
in controller but that button is not working,

Here is controller file/code

```
$user['result']=$this->crud->AddMember($data);
foreach($user['result'] as $row) {
    echo "<td>";
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item')">
    </form>';
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Here is view file

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FlatNumber" name="FlatNumber" placeholder="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="butsave">Add Details</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butsave').on('click', function() {

        event.preventDefault();  
        var FlatNumber = $('#FlatNumber').val();
        if(FlatNumber == '') {  
            alert("Please enter Flat Number");
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/Member/AddRecord'?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {FlatNumber : FlatNumber},
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(msg){
                        alert(msg);
                        if (msg == 'exist') {
                            $("#successs").hide();
                        }else{
                            $("#errorr").hide();
                        }
                    }
            });
        }  
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: what should happen when user click `ok` ?

Comment: why you are using `onclick="return confirm(''};` in `<input type="submit">` of Controller Code??

Answer (score 0):

It is because onclick works only for elements who already on this page. after ajax response it will not work so you need to use code like this.

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-danger", function(){
});
```